# Cannot Update Facebook page app custom_image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to update my page app image with graph api but nothing happens. i have right access token , i could change the custom_name but not custom_image.

```
                    var fbdc = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    fbdc.Add("access_token", AccessToken);
                    fbdc.Add("custom_name", Name);
                    fbdc.Add("custom_image",Image);
                    result = fb.Post(tab.id, fbdc);
```

I get the result true from graph api but still the image doesnt change.My image is 111*74.jpg. i was able to upload the same image manually but not through graph api.
Am i doing some thing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fbparams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          string path = @"c:\test.jpg";
          FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      var picture = new FacebookMediaObject
                {
                        //Tell facebook that we are sending image
                    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                    //Give name to the image
                    FileName = "test"
                };
                //Create a new byteArray with right length
                var img = tabImageInfo.Media;
                //Convert the image content into bytearray
               fs.Read(img, 0, img.Length);
                 //Close the stream
               fs.Close();
                //Put the bytearray into Picture
                picture.SetValue(img);
                //Add the image into parameters
                fbparams.Add("custom_image", picture);
        fb.Post(tab.id, fbparams);
```